# Large signal vs small signal analysis of Differential amplifiers

Tags: amplifier, analog, circuit-design, cmos, differential

Here is a question from the textbook "Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits" (Razavi)-
Assuming the circuit shown is symmetric, sketch Vout as (a) Vin1 and Vin2 vary differentially from zero to VDD, and (b) Vin1 and Vin2 are equal and they vary from zero to VDD
[image]
I did solve it but I don't think my technique is correct. I am finding it a little difficult (and non-intuitive) to write equations and solve for large signal variables in complicated circuits like in this problem, and none of the solutions I have seen so far have explained how they got the final Vout vs Vin plots. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: `I did solve it but I don't think my technique is correct.` Then can you show us what you have so far by editing your question? It's not possible to know what you did wrong if you won't show us.

Comment: I assumed all the mosfets are in saturation when the differential input is very small, and wrote KCL equations at the drain of M1 and at the drain of M3. From these, I got (Vin1-Vp-Vth1) directly proportional to (Vdd-Vout1-Vth3) where Vp is the potential at the source of M1. In small signal, Vp could be assumed to be zero. But that assumption would not be true in large scale analysis here, right? Especially since diff Vin varies from 0 to Vdd?